# How to recursively modify nested properties in parsed JSON object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, odata, traversal

I have parsed JSON object representing response from old OData(v2) service:

```
"TimesheetDetailsSet": {
    "results": [{
        "TimesheetNumber": "1",
        (...)
            "results": [{
                "__metadata":
```

So as you can see its a complex object with nested objects and arrays. I use SAP UI5 framework and I need to modify it, so there will be no intermediary arrays called "results". I want "TimesheetDetailsSet" and other entitysets containg "results" to be independent arrays of objects.

I wrote this method:

```
var fnConvert = function (oData) {

    if (!oData) {
        return oData;
    }

    for (var sKey in oData) {
        if (oData.hasOwnProperty(sKey)) {
            if (sKey == 'results') {
                var oArr = oData[sKey].reduce(function (acc, cur, i) {
                    acc[i] = cur;
                    return acc;
                }, []);

                delete oData[sKey]
                for (var i = 0; i < oArr.length; i++) {
                    oData[i] = oArr[i];
                    fnConvert(oData[i]);
                }

            } else if (typeof oData[sKey] === 'object') {
                fnConvert(oData[sKey]);
            }
        }
    }
    return oData;
};
```

The only problem is that need entitysets to be arrays not objects.

[Result of the method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8oeq.png)

UPDATE:

I got this:

```
"TimesheetDetailsSet": {
    "results": [{
        "__metadata": {
            "id": "...",
            "uri": "...",
            "type": "ZHR_XSS_ASA_ESS_ODATA_SRV.TimesheetDetails"
        },
        "TimesheetNumber": "1",
        "Username": "DEFAULT_USER",
        "TimesheetKey": "\/Date(1529280000000)\/",
        "TimesheetDetailKey": "00000001-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "CostObject": "0001",
        "ConstructionSiteSet": {
            "results": [{
                "__metadata": {
                    "id": "...",
                    "uri": "...",
                    "type": "ZHR_XSS_ASA_ESS_ODATA_SRV.ConstructionSite"
                },
                "TimesheetKey": "\/Date(1529280000000)\/",
                "WorkingOnConstrSiteSince": "18.08.2018",
                "Username": "DEFAULT_USER",
                "TimesheetDetailKey": "00000001-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "ConstructionSiteKey": "00000100-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "ConstructionSiteId": "0001",
                "ConstructionSiteDetailSet": {
                    "results": [{
                        "__metadata": {
                            "id": "...",
                            "uri": "...",
                            "type": "ZHR_XSS_ASA_ESS_ODATA_SRV.ConstructionSiteDetail"
                        },
```

And I want to change it into this:

```
"TimesheetDetailsSet": [{
        "__metadata": {
            "id": "...",
            "uri": "...",
            "type": "ZHR_XSS_ASA_ESS_ODATA_SRV.TimesheetDetails"
        },
        "TimesheetNumber": "1",
        "Username": "DEFAULT_USER",
        "TimesheetKey": "\/Date(1529280000000)\/",
        "TimesheetDetailKey": "00000001-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "CostObject": "0001",
        "ConstructionSiteSet": [{
                "__metadata": {
                    "id": "...",
                    "uri": "...",
                    "type": "ZHR_XSS_ASA_ESS_ODATA_SRV.ConstructionSite"
                },
                "TimesheetKey": "\/Date(1529280000000)\/",
                "WorkingOnConstrSiteSince": "18.08.2018",
                "Username": "DEFAULT_USER",
                "TimesheetDetailKey": "00000001-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "ConstructionSiteKey": "00000100-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "ConstructionSiteId": "0001",
                "ConstructionSiteDetailSet": [{
                        "__metadata": {
                            "id": "...",
                            "uri": "...",
                            "type": "ZHR_XSS_ASA_ESS_ODATA_SRV.ConstructionSiteDetail"
                        },
```

Comment: *"...parsed JSON object."* Once you've parsed it, it's not JSON anymore. :-) JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: In your code, what exactly does `oData` refer to? Because what you've quoted at the top of the question is a fragment of something, not valid JSON (or a valid JavaScript object initializer). Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Comment: At least related: [*Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json).

Comment: By JSON object I mean: var data = JSON.parse(rawJsonData). And then: var result = fnConvert(data).

Comment: It's probably easier to generate a new object, than to modify the existing one. You might want to add some valid JSON as well, it's hard to guess what your data looks like with your description

Comment: But to traverse existing object I need to use recursion.

Comment: *is that need entitysets to be arrays not objects.* what's *entitysets* mean?

Comment: @MacKarczewski - Right. That's just an object, not a "JSON object."

Comment: @MacKarczewski - Your update is still fragmentary. The top-level will start with `[` or `{`, not with `"`.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder - Its only a fragment of huge payload (162 lines when formated). It's a standard JSON file parsed to object. It's used by the framework (SAP UI5) as model (MVC) in binding process.

Comment: @MacKarczewski - Then it's your job to reduce it to a valid [mcve] so people can help you.

Comment: If all you want is an array instead of an object, you can use assign to copy your object to an empty array : 
`var result = Object.assign([], fnConvert(data))`